# Chi square matrix residuals

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared

below is a function to extract p-values from multiple Chi-Square tests and display them as a matrix. I'm trying to do the same, but to extract residuals instead. Any help is appreciated.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(first_column  = c(rep("E1_C1",5), rep("E1_C2",3), rep("E2_C2",7),rep("E3_C3",5)),
                  second_column = c(rep("E1_C1",3), rep("E1_C2",10), rep("E2_C2",4),rep("E3_C3",3)),
                  third_column = c(rep("E1_C1",7), rep("E1_C2",4), rep("E2_C2",3),rep("E3_C3",6)),
                  fourth_column = c(rep("E1_C1",4), rep("E1_C2",6), rep("E2_C2",6),rep("E3_C3",4))
)
```

Chi-square matrix function for P-Values:

```
chisqmatrix <- function(x) {
  names = colnames(x);  num = length(names)
  m = matrix(nrow=num,ncol=num,dimnames=list(names,names))
  for (i in 1:(num-1)) {
    for (j in (i+1):num) {
      #browser()
      m[j,i] = chisq.test(x[, i, drop = TRUE],x[, j, drop = TRUE])$p.value
    }
  }
  return (m)
}
```

Generate Chi-Square p-value matrix

```
res <- chisqmatrix(df)
res[, -ncol(res)]
```

Comment: `combn(df, 2, function(x) chisq.test(x[[1]], x[[2]])[['residuals']], simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks for this. However, is there a way to make it a bit more readble (e.g. col and row names). For example, the last two lines of code above display something similar to a correlation matrix. I'd like to ultimately generate a plot of the residuals similar to what's been done here - http://sthda.com/english/wiki/chi-square-test-of-independence-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the returned residuals is a 4x4 matrix. Instead of using a matrix to take the results, the following solution uses a list instead. This way you can have matrices of different sizes.

With minimal changes from your original code:

```
chisqlist <- function(x) {
  names = colnames(x);  num = length(names)
  m = list()
  index = 1
  for (i in 1:(num-1)) {
    for (j in (i+1):num) {
      #browser()
      m[[index]] = chisq.test(x[, i, drop = TRUE],x[, j, drop = TRUE])$residuals
      index=index+1
    }
  }
  return (m)
}
```

Edit:
I do prefer @ Onyambu's answer, which I didn't see. It would be faster than a nested for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your function from requesting $p.value to requesting $residuals.  This will provide (observed - expected) / sqrt(expected).  If you desire standardized residuals request $stdres.

```
  chisqmatrix <- function(x) {
    names = colnames(x);  num = length(names)
    m = matrix(nrow=num,ncol=num,dimnames=list(names,names))
    for (i in 1:(num-1)) {
      for (j in (i+1):num) {
        #browser()
        m[j,i] = chisq.test(x[, i, drop = TRUE],x[, j, drop = TRUE])$residuals
      }
    }
    return (m)
  }
```

Comment: You do realize residuals is a vector? and `m[i, j]` only takes in a value. So this is not correct